# Save video to custom album in camera roll

Tags: ios, ios5, video, alassetslibrary

I am able to save an image into a custom album in the iPhone camera roll. For example, the album name could be "Fun", and all of the images I take will go into that folder. I came across a helper class [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) that works very well to accomplish what I want.

However, the method I am using does not save videos into the custom folder, but the folder is created - it's just empty of any videos that I attempt to save there. I tried debugging it with no progress. That method is here:

```
-(void)addAssetURL:(NSURL*)assetURL toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:(SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
__block BOOL albumWasFound = NO;

    //search all photo albums in the library
[self enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum 
                    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                        //compare the names of the albums
                        if ([albumName compare: [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]]==NSOrderedSame) {
                            //target album is found
                            albumWasFound = YES;

                            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:assetURL];
                            if ([data length] > 0) {
                                //get a hold of the photo's asset instance
                                [self assetForURL: assetURL 
                                      resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

                                          [group addAsset: asset];

                                          //run the completion block
                                          completionBlock(nil);

                                      } failureBlock: completionBlock];
                            }

                            //album was found, bail out of the method
                            return;
                        }

                        if (group==nil && albumWasFound==NO) {
                            //photo albums are over, target album does not exist, thus create it

                            __weak ALAssetsLibrary* weakSelf = self;

                            //create new assets album
                            [self addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:albumName 
                                                  resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {

                                                      //get the photo's instance
                                                      [weakSelf assetForURL: assetURL 
                                                                    resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                                                        NSLog(@"asset: %@",asset);
                                                                        //add photo to the newly created album
                                                                        [group addAsset: asset];

                                                                        //call the completion block
                                                                        completionBlock(nil);

                                                                    } failureBlock: completionBlock];

                                                  } failureBlock: completionBlock];

                            //should be the last iteration anyway, but just in case
                            return;
                        }

                    } failureBlock: completionBlock];

}
```

Does anyone know the proper way to save a video into a custom album in the photo library?

Comment: Your code looks like its from http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/ .

This script is still not stable (please read the comments in that page)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
-(void)saveVideo:(NSURL *)videoUrl toAlbum:(NSString*)albumName withCompletionBlock:  (SaveImageCompletion)completionBlock
{
    //write the image data to the assets library (camera roll)
    [self writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL* assetURL, NSError* error) {

                       //error handling
                       if (error!=nil) {
                           completionBlock(error);
                           return;
                       }

                       //add the asset to the custom photo album
                       [self addAssetURL: assetURL
                                 toAlbum:albumName
                     withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

                   }];
```

}