# Saving video to custom album in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to write my own camera app for iphone. I am able to save photo and video to camera roll successfully. Now, i am trying out to save photo and video to custom album. I am able to save photo to custom album with some help from browsing. Also, i tried finding out if it is possible do the same with video. But, i was not able to do it and couldn't find the solution. Can someone help me with this?
Similar question which is un-answered:
[Save video to custom album in camera roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721988/save-video-to-custom-album-in-camera-roll)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721988/save-video-to-custom-album-in-camera-roll) is basically right, but you have to call `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);` 
first in UIImagePickerController delegate method:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```