# Save Video to specific folder

Tags: ios, video, save, alassetslibrary, photo-gallery

I'm saving a video to my PhotosAlbum, using this code:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
    {
         NSError *removeError = nil;
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoPath] error:&removeError];
    });
```

The video goes to the folder **Videos**  but i want it to go to a specific folder with the name of the app. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: then u have to save in sandbox

Comment: try inside blocks [self addAssetURL:pathUrl  toAlbum:folderName withCompletionBlock:completionBlock];

Comment: Where? After? Inside?

Comment: below answer is working or not

Comment: No. It has error and i'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
 ALAssetsLibrary* assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
 [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    [assetLibrary addAssetURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]  toAlbum:@"" completion:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSError* removeError = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] error:&removeError];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
}];
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721988/save-video-to-custom-album-in-camera-roll?rq=1

Comment: Your pathUrl just comes out of nowhere, it's a bit incomplete. Seems like copied from somewhere and dumped here.

Comment: let me ask one question, which one is dumbed above code or URL

Comment: no one is answer for this question but i try to answer for ur question u said i dumbed code from some where, currently working on record video with animation and save it to local and also in photoalbum folder

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but i want to save to a specific folder in photo album. For example [self addAssetURL...] does not exists, [assetLibrary addAssetURL...] is the correct code.

Comment: try this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569505/saving-video-in-an-album-created

Comment: Change the code in the comment above ande replace pathUrl with assetURL and i will accept your answer.

Comment: [self addAssetURL...] does not exists, change it to [assetLibrary addAssetURL...] like i already said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58872/discussion-between-ramesh-kumar-and-bruno).